# Dns doesn't return answer and it has no errorcode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns

The DNS response doesn't return and answer section, only an authority section.
The DNS is running on a docker based on the `sameersbn/bind` image.
Here are the bind files:

`/etc/bind/named.conf/`

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

```
zone "ben.com" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/ben.com.hosts";
        };
```

`/var/lib/bind/ben.com.hosts`

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     masterdns.ben.com. root.ben.com. (
        100         ;Serial
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
@       IN  NS          masterdns.ben.com.
@       IN  A           11.0.0.10
@       IN  A           11.0.0.11
@       IN  A           11.0.0.12
@       IN  A           11.0.0.13

masterdns               IN  A   11.0.0.10
webserver1              IN  A   11.0.0.11
webserver2              IN  A   11.0.0.12
nginx                   IN  A   11.0.0.13
```

`Response from dns`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.5 <<>> masterdns.ben.com @172.18.0.2
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 28334
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;masterdns.ben.com.             IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ben.com.                38400   IN      SOA     10.0.0.20. benshalev849.gmail.com. 1624192868 10800 3600 604800 38400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 172.18.0.2#53(172.18.0.2)
;; WHEN: Sun Jun 20 13:01:21 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 113
```

Comment: Are you sure you're querying the correct server? (What is 172.18.0.2? What happens if the BIND container is shut down?)

Comment: 172.18.0.2 is the actual ip of the container, port 53 is port forwarded to it via the VM port (10.0.0.20:53) is port forwarded to (172.18.0.2).
When it's shutdown it says `connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Comment: In that case, make sure you don't have _two_ `zone "ben.com"` blocks somewhere in the configuration?